# Only 1 instance using Mutex misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, mutex

```
class OneAtATimePlease
{
    static void Main()
    {

        using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, "oreilly.com OneAtATimeDemo"))
        {
            if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), false))
                RunProgram();
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Another instance of the app is running. Bye!");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    static void RunProgram()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running. Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

but those lines waits for someone to call `Set()` function :

```
 if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), false))
                RunProgram();
```

who is calling `set` here ? this  thread will *never* be released...(or will?)

what am i missing ?

Comment: On exit, the program which runs the mutex will exit, causing mutex.WaitOne to return on the others....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WaitOne() immediately returns with a true if someone's not running it. Else, it blocks! The program which then finishes, causes one of the waiting programs to return with a true immediately.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx **Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal.** ????

Comment: Yes. a signal is thrown on program exit.

Comment: if i activated my program and only running 1 instance , will it return  true ? ( there wont be a  signal which is thrown on program exitsince there is no program exit)

Comment: yes. Technically, one is supposed to run a mutex.releaseMutex() after RunProgram()... Else, you'll leave the mutex in a dangling state... I think you should read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex.aspx ... Prior to .net 2, that was an acceptable way to do single instances. Just that today, it isn't documented as acceptable behavior anymore.

Comment: _WaitOne() immediately returns with a true if someone's not running it_ where does it written ?

Comment: it returns true if nobody else is currently using the exact named mutex here. After the thread that owns the mutex relinquishes the mutex it got, one of the others who are blocked on the call gets unblocked....